# Why do I get a "Access to the path denied" error when path doesn't even exist

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I get the following intermittent error in my asp.net application

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\[path to file]' is denied.
```

The application is trying to open the file when this error occurs, but when I check the path and file I discover that it doesn't actually exist.  Shouldn't I be getting a 'file not found' type error? Can someone explain how this could be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure (in that I don't have a link to back this up) but my guess is that IIS suppresses file exist errors to prevent the possibility of systematically testing a multitude of different paths/files determine an applications folder/file structure.

Much in the same way you shouldn't display a login message saying email exists but the password is wrong, which would allow someone to fish for emails.